# UnityとC#でのゲーム作り

Tags: c#

#### 解決したいこと

C#とUnityで簡単なゲームを作っています。
実行すると次のようなエラーが出てしまいました。
どうしたらいいでしょうか？

#### 発生している問題・エラー

```
(10,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `UnityEngine' 
could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

#### 該当するソースコード

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: 参考にしたり基にしている書籍やWeb上の記事があれば追記してください。それらと何か違うこととか手順を省略したりしていませんか？ `UnityEngine`という`namespace`が見つからないというエラーなので、割と基本的な部分で何かを間違えている可能性が考えられます。それから今の質問記事だと内容が少なくて現象を再現したり状況を特定したりするための情報が不足しています。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に詳細を追記してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: https://zenn.dev/nok_c7/articles/c9b59cf32134f2 この記事を参考にしました

Comment: コメントで紹介された記事の中のどれかの手順が抜けているか間違って実行・指定している可能性が考えられます。また記事末尾の参考URLに紹介された記事の方も見た方が良いでしょう。ちなみに類似の記事だとこんなものがあるでしょう。[【Unity】UnityのエディタをVSCodeに設定する手順(Macの場合)](https://rurugamedev-blog.com/entry/2023/04/30/%E3%80%90Unity%E3%80%91Unity%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A8%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%82%BF%E3%82%92VSCode%E3%81%AB%E8%A8%AD%E5%AE%9A%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E6%89%8B%E9%A0%86%28Mac%E3%81%AE%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88%29)

Answer (score 0):

Unity の Console にエラーが出力されているのでなく、Visual Studio にのみエラーが表示されていると推測しています。
そうであれば、[Visual Studio を Unity から使うように統合されていない](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g25bfk0ltCM&t=324s&pp=ygUadW5pdHkgdmlzdWFsIHN0dWRpbyDpgKPmkLo%3D)からでしょう。